# What happen internally when I set `bufhidden` to `delete`?

Tags: buffers

As title. Would the buffer I set the option with the value `delete` really get deleted immediately? If not, when will it be deleted and what is this mechanism? Sorry for maybe a bad question but I'm trying to learn Vim's buffers mechanism.

Btw, I also read a special type of buffers called `directory` and these buffers have this option set to `delete` from the start. So I guess my intuition could be correct that these buffers are "about to be deleted" but I'm still curious about what will happen behind the scene. (If that's the case, then I also want to know whether "recovery from a set-to-`delete` buffer" is possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would the buffer I set the option with the value delete really get deleted immediately? If not, when will it be deleted and what is this mechanism?

"When" stands for "when buffer is not displayed in any window anymore", or, in other words, when `BufWinLeave` event gets triggered.

"What" is "bdelete" command (or equivalent).

Also, there's no "directory" buftype. If some buffer gets "bufhidden" non-empty value then it should be due to a plugin.

Comment: "Also, there's no "directory" buftype": Yes, there is. I'm using neovim and it's under the section `:h special-buffers`. The title of that manual is `VIM REFERENCE MANUAL    by Bram Moolenaar`.

Comment: "when `BufWinLeave` event gets triggered": Do you have any reference for your words?

Comment: Your problem that you read very unattentively. The buftype option value is "nofile". "Directory" is "kind of", that is an informal explanation what that thing could be used for. It appears nowhere else. Also, I don't understand what is "a reference"? I tell what I know, and I know pretty much, when it comes to Vim, I dare say.

Comment: OK, I believe your words. So my conclusion is: This kind of buffer "directory" is a buffer that will be deleted immediately on `BufWinLeave` when it disappears from all of my tabpages. By "deleted" it means the data structure will be freed (so it's null, not just empty), correct?

Comment: By reference, I meant for example (if possible) you could show a reference to the source code where it indeed shows some "dealloc"s are called when the event `BufWinLeave` happens. This way if someone else asks me the same then I can confidently use/post your answer as a reference, too. Nevermind, I will remember your answer and try to prove it myself in the future.

Comment: What it does is "bdelete". But what exactly does "bdelete" is yet another question.

Comment: Perhaps by "reference" @job_start means "citation" or "source"—it is standard to provide evidence for claims. For example, the "when" question is answered by `:help bufhidden`'s first sentence.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I don't see why should I dig into the source code while even `:h 'bufhidden'` upholds this (pretty obvious, I believe) assertion.